# Undefined Value when trying to get return value from another class' function

Tags: php, pdo

When i try to get the returned value of a function in another class i get Undefined Variable. $dbh is null

at my entry point file i instantiate a DB_Functions object:

```
require_once ('/DB_Functions.php');
$db = new DB_Functions();
```

this is on DB_Function.php file.

```
   class DB_Functions {
        private $db;
        public $dbh;

        //put your code here
        // constructor
        function __construct() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            // connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->dbh = $this->db->connect();
        }
    }
```

then i use the db object like that:

```
    if ($db->isUserExisted($username)) {}....
```

The error is inside `isUserExisted(...)` function. Line 89 is $statement = $dbh....:

```
  public function isUserExisted($username) {
        $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
}
```

This is in DB_Connect.php file that instantiates the PDO object and returns it

```
public function connect() {
        require_once('config.php');
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . hostname . ';dbname=' . db_name, username, password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        echo 'Connected to database';
        return $dbh;
}
```

Error is:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\pharm_project\DB_Functions.php on line 89

Line 89 is:

> $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username
>   = :username");

Comment: I'm assuming the first file is pharm_project\DB_Functions? Where is line 89? Sorry for all the question, crystal ball is broken.

Comment: in line 89 i try to use the PDO object

Comment: So DB_Functions.php:89 is `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . hostname . ';dbname=' . db_name, username, password);`?

Comment: this is line 89---->  $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");

Comment: Why would you not include that super useful information in your question? You need to put in that, and all the code around it...

Comment: [please read over this for a second](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I did, please include the code from where `$dbh` is set up to line 89...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
public function isUserExisted($username) {
    $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
}
```

`$dbh` does not exist inside the scope of this function. You will either need to pass in the database connection as an argument (as in `isUserExisted($dbh, $username)`) or store it in the object you're calling that function on.

For example, in that objects `__construct()`, you might do `$this->dbh = $dbh` or something. Then your function would change to

```
public function isUserExisted($username) {
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
}
```

[More information can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)